# sqlite timestamp

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I created a database using the following sql statement

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "+ TABLE_USERLOCATION + "("
+ COLUMN_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
+ COLUMN_LONGITUDE +" real not null, "
+ COLUMN_LATITUDE+" real not null, "
+ COLUMN_TIME + " timestamp not null default current_timestamp);";
```

When I try to get COLUMN_TIME via

```
cursor.getColumnIndex(GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_TIME)
```

I get -1 (so obviously an error)

But when I cd into the database directory in my emulator and have a look at all the entries, I see that a timestamp has been added:

1|2.71828|3.14159166666667|2013-04-09 00:05:50

2|2.71828|3.14159166666667|2013-04-09 00:35:09

How can I access the date and why does getColumnCount() return 3 instead of 4?

I worked through[this](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=413) tutorial (my table creation statement is basically similiar to that one presented there).

Cheers

Comment: What is your `SELECT` statement or `query()`?

Comment: Make sure there is no leading space in your `COLUMN_TIME`, i.e. `public static final String COLUMN_TIME = " time";`

Comment: What is the query for that cursor?

Comment: private String[] allColumns = {GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_ID, GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE}; 



long insertId = database.insert(GPSSqliteHelper.TABLE_USERLOCATION, null,values);
Cursor cursor = database.query(GPSSqliteHelper.TABLE_USERLOCATION, allColumns, GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_ID+" = "+ insertId, null, null, null, null);

I checked whether there is any whitespace in the names of the columns. This is not the case.

Comment: values is a ContentValue Object with the latitude and logitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly too late, but in case someone came here with the same problem...

COLUMN_TIME is not declared in allColumns, it should be:

`private String[] allColumns = {GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_ID, GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_LATITUDE, GPSSqliteHelper.COLUMN_TIME}`

Answer (score -3):

sqlite does not use a timestamp type.  You should create the date as text.  See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

This is what I do, and then you can manipulate the date string as you wish in your code.

Comment: Though it is not listed on that page, [timestamp](https://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html) is a valid SQLite data type.

Comment: this is technically true, but from the looks of their documentation, they 'encourage' the use of their built-in date and time functions and they state that they 'do NOT have a storage class set aside specifically for dates and times'.  Nevertheless, I have always used my dates/timestamps as they recommend and never had an issue

Comment: and I am speaking of SQLite3, not version 2, sorry about the confusion

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` does create a timestamp in SQLite's preferred format.

Comment: current_timestamp is a text representative of the time, not a type

Comment: Storing date as text? Seriously!?